# ByPass jQuery Plug-in OnClick Function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the following jQuery plug-in, i.e:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html

The issue I am having though is that, as part of the call to the api, it seems to make us of the `onClick()` function within the plug-in js file.

I actually want to use the `onClick` function as your normal javascript `onClick()` function but I am not able to as it seems to be overridden with the following code:

```
                // assign onClick events to existing entries
            } else {

                // find a entries first -> syntaxically correct
                var els = nav.children(); 

                els.each(function(i)  {
                    var item = $(this);
                    item.attr("href", i);
                    if (i === 0) { item.addClass(conf.activeClass); }

                    item.click(function() {
                        nav.find("." + conf.activeClass).removeClass(conf.activeClass);
                        item.addClass(conf.activeClass);
                        self.setPage(item.attr("href"));
                    });

                });
            }

        });


        // item.click()
        if (conf.clickable) {
            self.getItems().each(function(index, arg) {
                var el = $(this);
                if (!el.data("set")) {
                    el.bind("click.scrollable", function() {
                        self.click(index);      
                    });
                    el.data("set", true);
                }
            });             
        }
```

Is there anyway of bypassing this, so that I can use the standalone `onClick()` function?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the code. You can check it out.

Comment: Yes. Its the `removeitem` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that they haven't given a `callback` function to call back to. You can modify their JS code to do this -

```
item.click(function() {
    nav.find("." + conf.activeClass).removeClass(conf.activeClass);
    item.addClass(conf.activeClass);
    self.setPage(item.attr("href"));
    if(typeof(clickCallback) != "undefined") clickCallback();
});
```

So, if you have a function called `clickCallback` defined on your page, you'll now be able to handle the click event after their click event code has been executed -

```
function clickCallback() {
    //This is the function on your page. This will be called when you click the item.
}
```

You don't have to call the `clickCallback` function, the library will itself call that function if its been defined.

Comment: Thanks for that Kirtan but I am still unsure how to actually use/call the clickCallback function? At the moment I am using he onClick function as onClick="removeitem();" but the above code is taking over. What do I do with clickCallback?

Comment: Thanks for your response - so based on your function clickCallback, this is in actual fact my removeitem() function in place of your clickCallBack function - yes?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own click event handler and stop propagation of the event there.

```
$('your selector').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```